# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors to find $A\textbf{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix with eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} 3\\ 0\\ -2\end{bmatrix}$ corresponding to an eigenvalue of $5$ and $\begin{bmatrix} -1\\ 2\\ 7\end{bmatrix}$ corresponding to an eigenvalue of $2$, and $\textbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}10 \\ 4 \\10\end{bmatrix}$ find $A\textbf{v}$.

My attempt at solving this problem was to begin by stating that $Ax=\lambda x$, Where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue and $x$ is the eigenvector and then saying that $$A=5*(3,0,-2)+2*(-1,2,7)=(13,4,4)=A.$$ Then I followed by saying that $Av=(13,4,4)*(10,4,10)=186$ but I'm sure If I'm moving in the right direction..

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you. You must tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck to receive help.

Comment: My attempt at the solution is clearly stated above thank you.

Comment: Why did you write $A$ as a 1x3 matrix when it says that it is a 3x3?

Comment: What is the vector v ? What does it represent ? Tell me and I'll give you the full answer below because it seems you have misunderstood things about that.

Comment: v represents the eigenvector of A ?

Comment: What do you mean "the". There are 3 eigenvectors for a 3x3 matrix. The other 2 are defined as eigenvectors. The vector v is not defined as an eigenvector. Look at the exercise you posted. Define what v is.

Comment: As a Linear Algebra enthusiast, which means I have read tons of stuff, what I understand from this exercise is that v is just a random vector that wants you to multiply it with A, after you've found A.

Comment: I find that to be confusing that v is defined as (10,4,10) but you are saying that v just a random vector, how is that possible?

Comment: By random, I mean that v is not an eigenvector.

Comment: Anyway, I gave you an analytic answer down below explaining everything, check it out and don't forget to vote up and approve it if it makes you understand your exercise.

Answer (score 1):

With the eigenvectors and eigenvalues 
$$
v_1 = (3,  0, -2)^t \quad \lambda_1 = 5 \\
v_2 = (-1, 2, 7)^t \quad \lambda_2 = 2
$$
the systems $A v_i = \lambda_i$ give only $6$ equations for the $9$ unknown matrix elements $a_{ij}$.

It turns out that $v = (10,4,10) \not\in \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle$: 
We have to choose 
$$
v = 2 v_2 + c v_1 = (3c-2, 4, -2c + 14)
$$ 
because of the middle component. To get the first component right, we need $c = 4$, to get the third component right, we need $c = 2$. 
Otherwise we could have used
$$
A v = A (c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2) = c_1 (A v_1) + c_2 (A v_2) = 5 c_1 v_1 + 2 c_2 v_2
$$

So this problem seems not to have a unique solution.

One possible solution is
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 3/2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-10/3 & 16/3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
For this matrix we have $A v = (56, 8, -12)^t$.

This matrix $A$ was derived from the system
$$
[M|b] =
\left[ 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr|r}
   3 &   0 &  -2&    0 &   0 &   0 &   0 &   0  &  0 &  15 \\
   0 &   0 &  0  &  3   & 0  & -2  &  0  &  0   & 0  &  0\\
   0 &   0 &   0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  3 &   0  & -2 & -10\\
  -1 &   2 &   7  &  0  &  0  &  0 &   0  &  0  &  0 &  -2\\
   0 &   0 &  0  & -1  &  2  &  7  &  0 &  0  &  0  &  4\\
   0 &   0 &   0  &  0  &  0  &  0  & -1 &   2 &   7 &  14\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and its row echelon form
$$
\left[ 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr|r}
  1 & 0 &-2/3   &   0 & 0 & 0     &   0 &0 & 0      &  5    \\   
  0 & 1 & 19/6  &   0 & 0 & 0     &   0 &0 & 0      &  3/2   \\
  0 & 0 & 0     &   1 & 0 & -2/3  &   0 &0 & 0      &  0    \\
  0 & 0 & 0     &   0 & 1 & 19/6  &   0 &0 & 0      &  2    \\
  0 & 0 & 0     &   0 & 0 & 0     &   1 &0 & -2/3   &  -10/3 \\
  0 & 0 & 0     &   0 & 0 & 0     &   0 &1 & 19/6   &  16/3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
which can be extended into
$$
\left[ 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrr|r}
  1 & 0 &-2/3   &   0 & 0 & 0     &   0 &0 & 0      &  5    \\   
  0 & 1 & 19/6  &   0 & 0 & 0     &   0 &0 & 0      &  3/2   \\
  0 & 0 & 1     &   0 & 0 & 0     &   0 &0 & 0      &  a_{13} \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0     &   1 & 0 & -2/3  &   0 &0 & 0      &  0    \\
  0 & 0 & 0     &   0 & 1 & 19/6  &   0 &0 & 0      &  2    \\
  0 & 0 & 0     & 0 & 0 & 1     &      0 &0 & 0      &  a_{23} \\ 
  0 & 0 & 0     &   0 & 0 & 0     &   1 &0 & -2/3   &  -10/3 \\
  0 & 0 & 0     &   0 & 0 & 0     &   0 &1 & 19/6   &  16/3 \\
   0 & 0 & 0     &   0 &0 & 0  &  0 & 0 & 1         &  a_{33} \\ 
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and where the unknowns are the matrix elements $x = (a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{13}, a_{21}, \dotsc, a_{33})^t$.

Answer (score 0):

$Ax = λx \Leftrightarrow (Α-λ)x = 0$

Let :

$ A =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\
a_7 & a_8 & a_9 \end{array} \right) $

Then, $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\
a_7 & a_8 & a_9 \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3  \\
0  \\
-2  \end{array} \right) = 5 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3  \\
0  \\
-2  \end{array} \right)  $

and

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\
a_7 & a_8 & a_9 \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 \\
2 \\
7  \end{array} \right) = 2 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1  \\
2  \\
7  \end{array} \right)  $

Proceed first of all by solving the system that is created by the matrix equations above and you should be able to find the matrix $A$. After finding $A$, do the multiplication $Av$, where $v =[10,4,10]^T$ and find the solution to your exercise.

Comment: There are 9 unknowns , I tried to assemble the matrices regarding these ax=b systems and wasn't able to figure out any feasible way of determining matrix A

Comment: Maybe you are missing a part of the exercise because indeed the problem does not have a unique solution .Make sure that the exercise is exactly as you posted.

Comment: No the question is not missing anything i made sure to include everything the question asks for

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a real answer, just a sketch for the answer.

May A be 3 x 3 matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}  \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}  \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$

With

$Av = \lambda_1 v_1 \ , \ Av = \lambda_2 v_2$

I would solve those first and then proceed like you did before.